# How to hide/minimise the console of java.exe starts after execution of my bat file

Tags: java, batch-file

I am running a bat file which connects my jenkins agent with master , the bat file opens the agent.jar file with java.exe and it stays on the screen after connection the automated tests starts but due to that java.exe window is opened my test fails to identify the UI elements within the product because console file block the UI elements
Is there any way that after running my bat file I can minimise that java.exe windows programmatically/automatically ??

Following is my bat file

```
start java -jar "C:\Jenkins\agent.jar" -jnlpUrl http://localhost:7070/computer/TestingMachine/jenkins-agent.jnlp -secret 338e93b0b127faf70a56c0edec39a70804accd7157c49e1e37e3be14aa8ea8db -workDir "C:\Jenkins"
```

Comment: I'm not sure I got your problem right from your description, but you can try `start /min ...`. [See the docs for start.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start)

Comment: I suggest not using the Windows console version `java.exe` which on execution with command `start` results in opening a new console window. It is most likely better to use `javaw.exe` which is the Windows GUI version of *Java* on which execution no console window is opened by the Windows kernel library function `CreateProcess` used by `start`. That should solve your problem. There could be even removed `start` on using `javaw.exe` to let `cmd.exe` and so also *Jenkins* wait for the self-termination of `agent.jar` execution before continuation of batch file processing.

Comment: Thanks for the answers problem has been solved :)